# Marimekko chart cell titles not updating

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, marimekko-chart

I'm making a visualization for the titanic data set https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data, and after some search i found that the marimekko chart is the best visualization for this data set.

I looked at http://www.jasondavies.com/mekko/ and began to tweak the code a bit to fit it to my needs. My problem is that the cell titles (those appear after mouse - hover at a cell) do not update values. The first call to the function  ***chart*** draws the titles correctly, then when i try to change the cell values using the ***transition*** function, the charts animates properly but the values in the cell titles do not change, they still have the old values when i hover at them.

The last line in the ***transition*** function is:

```
cellEnter.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : title(d); });
```

which seems to work the first time the chart is drawn, but it doesn't update the titles when the cell data changes.

Any ideas how to fix this ?

If you're curious to see the changes i made, have a look at working example 
http://codepen.io/hshihab/pen/PqWjmo

I just made a couple of small changes to Jason's original code to show my point.

Comment: Your codepen says that `draw` is not defined and doesn't run for me.

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to make it work on codepen, here's the complete index.html http://pastebin.com/6q6xjKC3

Comment: You may need to specify a key function (second argument to `.data()`) that tells D3 how to match data and DOM elements.

Comment: Umm, not sure what do you mean, and are you talking about `.data(treemap.nodes);` ?

Comment: Yes. It's quite hard to figure out what's going on without being able to see what it does.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to use the `.data()` with the second argument as u suggested ?

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/)?

Comment: I tried providing a key function, i used a combination of both sex and state (survived or perished) and it didn't work out. So is there another workaround ?

Comment: Well this wouldn't be a workaround, but solving the solution properly :) I would encourage you to provide a complete working example that people can modify, you're much more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: Ok, i edited my question and added a link to a working example at codepen. Check it and tell me if you need more clarifications

Comment: Ah ok, looks like the problem is that the title is only appended the first time, not updated. [This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVxJPK) should do what you want.

Comment: Wow, You really saved me there man. Thanks a lot ! A really simple but elegant solution. I think what that tells me is that i have a lot to learn about d3.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lars Kotthoff pointed out in the comments, the last line in the **transition** function should be changed to:

```
cellEnter.append("title");
cellUpdate.select("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.children ? null : title(d);
  });
```